# Property addEventListener of null inside react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm using this code https://codepen.io/jotavejv/pen/bRdaVJ to add it to my react page.

When I click the **Browse** button it reloads the page instead of opening the file picker!

I have tried to add:

```
 async function componentDidMount() {
        $("#triggerFile").addEventListener("click", evt => {
          evt.preventDefault();
          $("input[type=file]").click();
        });  ...code continues
```

async does not work.. tried also with

```
  window.onload=function(){}
```

This too does not work!

When I add the code in a blank page ,it works fine but inside another page it gives me the above error.Smh it should wait for the page to load(or smth similar)

Can someone help me fix this?

thank you

Comment: What is `$`? jQuery? If yes, then why `.addEventListener()`?

Comment: @Andreas that is not my code..I simply want to add it to my react page.Yes I do think its Jquery

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing direct DOM access and React components.  If you do need to access the DOM in React you should be using refs.  https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Keith how would you fix this code to work inside the react,can you help?

Comment: and strange thing is that this works inside a blank page,but when copy paste code in another react page..does not

Answer (score 1):

An example of how it can be done in React in [this working repl](https://repl.it/@masterakos/GlitteringForcefulAnalysis).

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.inputRef = React.createRef();

    this.onBrowseClick = this.onBrowseClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    
  }

  onBrowseClick = () => {
    this.inputRef.current.click();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" style={{display: 'none'}} ref={this.inputRef}></input>
        <button onClick={this.onBrowseClick}>Browse</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I do not want any input file to open...I want to run the above code in another page...it works in a blank page the problem in when its with other code...please take a look at the question

Comment: Do it the React way instead of using jQuery.